# prevent same Images on cards in a row

Tags: javascript

I'm presenting `Cards` to a webpage. I want 3 cards per row. I'm pulling my data from `Firestore`. I have a `collection` called `userData`. `userData` contains the following fields `headerImage` `name` and `email`. I'm using the `map` method to iterate the objects. The name and email fields present correctly in the card but the image is the same for all cards in the row.

I'm using react, here is the map method to return the data from `Firestore`:

```
render() {

        return (
            <div className='container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center'>
                <div className='row'>
                    {this.state.userData.map(board =>
                    <div className='col-md-4'>
                        <Card  title={board.name} body={board.email} imgsrc={board.headerImage}/>
                    </div>

                )}

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Here is the `Card class` (I'm using bootstrap).

```
const Card = props => {
    return (
        <div className='card text-center shadow'>
            <div className='overflow'>
                <div className="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                <img src={props.imgsrc} alt='Image 1' className='card-img-top embed-responsive-item' />
                </div>

            </div>
            <div className='card-body text-dark'>
                <h4 className='card-title'>{props.title}</h4>
                <p className='card-text text-secondary'>{props.body}</p>
                <a href='#' className='btn btn-outline-success'>
                    Go Anywhere
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

and the css file..

```
body {
    background: radial-gradient(#e5e5e5, #ffff, #e5e5e5);
}

.card {
    width: 20rem;
}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.253) !important;
}

.card-body {
    padding: 3rem 0 !important;
}

.card-text {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    padding: 0.4rem 1.9rem;
}

.container-fluid .row {
    padding-top: 6rem;
}

.overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.card-img-top {
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

.card-img-top:hover {
    transform: scale(1.8);
}
```

Why is the same image populating all the cards in the same row with the same image while `name` and `email` work as intended.

Here is the webpage [image]

The picture field is called `headerImage`. And the obvious thing is to check if I have the same image in each item in the row...but I've doubled checked each item in the row has a different `imageHeader`. but if I change the image for Gerard Horgan all the images in the row change..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a key to the Card component?

```
{this.state.userData.map((board, index) =>
   <div className='col-md-4'>
      <Card key={index} title={board.name} body={board.email} imgsrc={board.headerImage}/>
   </div>

)}
```